# Mosquitto security error: OpenSSL Error: routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: node.js, security, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to store MQTT payloads in a MongoDB database using NodeJS.
When I run my code I get the following error popped up at the Mosquitto server:

```
1427756032: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1427756033: New connection from 146.175.138.141 on port 8883.
1427756033: OpenSSL Error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

I'm not the only one facing this error but the proposed solutions on google won't work for me.

I'm working in a Ubuntu14.04 TLS (trusty) server environment. The version of OpenSSL which I used to make my own keys and certificates is:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

For making these keys I followed the [manual](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html) of Mosquitto.

The version of nodejs is:

```
v0.10.25
```

The configuration file of mosquitto:

```
port 8883
cafile /etc/keys/ca.crt
certfile /etc/keys/server.crt
keyfile /etc/keys/server.key
tls_version tlsv1
require_certificate true
```

The nodejs file:

```
var mqtt=require('mqtt')
var mongodbClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var deviceRoot="demo/device/"
var mqtthost = '146.175.138.141';
var KEY = '/etc/keys/client.key';
var CERT = '/etc/keys/client.crt';
var CAfile = '/etc/keys/ca.crt';

var options = {
    host: mqtthost,
    port: 8883,
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    ca: CAfile,
    keyPath: KEY,
    certPath: CERT,
    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    protocolVersion: 3
};

var collection,client;

mongodbClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err,db){
 if(err){return console.dir(err);}

 collection=db.collection("test_mqtt");

 client=mqtt.connect(options);

 client.subscribe("#");
 client.publish(deviceRoot, '21');

 client.on('message', function(topic,payload){
  str = payload.toString();
  console.log(str);
  var key=topic.replace(deviceRoot,'');

  collection.update(
   { _id:key },
   { $push: { events: { event: { value:str, when:new Date() } } } },
   { upsert:true }
)})})
```

The keys should be working because publishing with the following command is not a problem:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 146.175.138.141 -p 8883 -t Server -m helloworld --cafile /etc/keys/ca.crt --cert /etc/keys/client.crt --key /etc/keys/client.key --tls-version tlsv1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "fs" guarantees access to the files

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongodbClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var deviceRoot="demo/device/"
var mqtthost = '146.175.138.141';
var KEY = fs.readFileSync('/etc/keys/client.key');
var CERT = fs.readFileSync('/etc/keys/client.crt');
var CAfile = [fs.readFileSync('/etc/keys/ca.crt')];

var options = {
host: mqtthost,
port: 8883,
protocol: 'mqtts',    //also add this
protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
ca: CAfile,
key: KEY,
cert: CERT,
secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
protocolVersion: 3
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but I suspect that your nodejs connection isn't using TLS. You could verify this by connecting with mosquitto_pub without passing `--cafile`:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 146.175.138.141 -p 8883 -t Server -m helloworld
```

That should produce the same error on the broker that you see with your nodejs connection.

The next step is to remove the `tls_version tlsv1` line from your mosquitto configuration and repeat the above command. In that case I would expect to get the following error message on the broker:

```
Client connection from ::1 failed: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol.
```

If you now repeat the test with your nodejs client and get the same error message, it is a fair bet that what I'm saying is correct. I'm afraid I don't know how to fix it though!

An easier test would be to leave your nodejs code unchanged, but set mosquitto to listen without using TLS. If node connects fine then it confirms the situation.

On a related note, if you are using mosquitto 1.4, the best option is to not force a particular version of TLS because the default behaviour is to allow TLS v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2. Earlier versions only provided a single version of TLS per listener.

Comment: Indeed, this error pops up if the broker can't find the cafile. And yes, If I remove the tls_version in the mosquitto configuration I get the "client_hello" error. If I set mosquitto to listen without using TLS the nodejs code is able to make connection. So you are right. 

Thank you for pointing me on the TLS settings. But my problem isn't solved ofcourse. Is it normal that the broker doesn't ask me for a pem passphrase anymore while starting it up? Could there be any ownership issues involved?

Comment: I don't think that mosquitto (the broker) is at fault because it works correctly with mosquitto_pub with TLS. The nodejs code isn't using TLS despite you telling it to. I can't help with that, sorry.